# How to make a compound generic type

Tags: python, python-typing

I'd like to make a generic compound type that will set different type hints (but related to each other) for different attributes of the class.

I got this:

```
from typing import Generic, Literal, NewType, TypeVar


AccessTokenType = TypeVar("AccessTokenType", bound=str)
RefreshTokenType = TypeVar("RefreshTokenType", bound=str)

XAccessToken = NewType("XAccessToken", AccessToken)
YAccessToken = NewType("YAccessToken", AccessToken)

XRefreshToken = NewType("XRefreshToken", RefreshToken)
YRefreshToken = NewType("YRefreshToken", RefreshToken)


class AuthorizationData(Generic[AccessTokenType, RefreshTokenType]):
    access_token: AccessTokenType
    refresh_token: RefreshTokenType


class AuthorizationDataSet:
    x: AuthorizationData[XAccessToken, XRefreshToken]
    y: AuthorizationData[YAccessToken, YRefreshToken]
```

I expect that tokens from the same group always will be set for one type inside `AuthorizationDataSet`.

I was wondering if there is a way to somehow make an inseparable compound type e.g., all X-related are together `AuthorizationData[TokenGroup.X]` would make `access_token: XAccessToken` & `refresh_token: XRefreshToken`.

Comment: The way you define `AccessTokenType` is not valid. Either add another constraint or make `str` the upper bound. Also you are missing imports. Aside from that, I really don't understand what you want to achieve here. Please edit the code to make it complete and reproducible, maybe just leave out the unclear type annotation for now and add an example of what should be caught as an error vs. what should pass as correct.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg, sorry, was a bit hectic. I've updated the question.

Comment: Code is still incomplete. What are `AccessToken` and `RefreshToken` used in your `NewType` definitions? Aren't `XAccessToken` etc. just supposed to be subtypes of `str`? Or is e.g. `AccessToken = NewType("AccessToken", str)`?

Comment: If I understood your intention correctly though, I think this may be yet another use case for [higher-kinded type variables](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548). But I am not sure.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg, that's exactly what I was looking for. Bummer it's not possible. Thanks anyway!